# Ruby hashes, getting a key which programatically changes

Tags: ruby

Quite difficult to explain, I would like to achieve the following:

In JavaScript, One would write:

```
var myKey = 'name',
    myObj = {name:'Joe', age:...};

name[ myKey ]; // Joe
```

I would like to achieve this in Ruby.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: This is exactly how you write it in ruby. The only difference is that you need to be aware of whether the key is a string or a symbol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby value of a hash key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054338/ruby-value-of-a-hash-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's almost the same:

```
my_key = :name
my_hash = { name: 'Joe', age: 52 }
my_hash[my_key]
#=> "Joe"
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html